# How to update records in SQL Server database through asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm writing this code in asp.net but still it's not updating record in a SQL Server database:

```
SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("Select * from roomdetail", conn);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd4.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("update [roomdetail] set [rid]=' " +count+1 + " '  where rid = 0 AND roomtype='"+typeRadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString()+        "' ", conn);
```

Comment: I don't think this even compiles because a declaration cannot be the body of a control flow block without braces. Additionally what is it that you're trying to achieve? Why do you do a `SELECT` query and then ignore the results?

Comment: it compiles successfully but does not update, i am using the select query in order to read the rows and to update the specified column according to the condition.

Comment: The code in your question will not compile successfully. Be precise when pasting.

Comment: You need to use parameters, you need to use using blocks, and you need some help. here is a great tutorial for you http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient

Comment: My fault at posting. Thanks for your  suggestion @MattiVirkkunen

Answer (score 2):

Proper way to use ado.net:

```
var newId = count + 1;
var roomType = typeRadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString();

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("your db connection string here"))
{
        var query = "UPDATE [roomdetail] SET [rid] = @rid WHERE [rid] = 0 AND roomtype = @roomType";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rid", newId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomType", roomType);

        try
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception
        }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the *really* proper way would be to put the `SqlCommand` into a `using(...) { .... }` block as well !

Answer (score 1):

You are Missing ExecuteNonQuery Method Write Below code

```
SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("Select * from roomdetail", conn);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd4.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("update [roomdetail] set [rid]=' " +count+1 + " '  where rid = 0 AND roomtype='"+typeRadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString()+        "' ", conn);
cmd3.executeNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the connection is already opened, in your while loop you are missing the following statement:

```
cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You have to execute the command in order for the database to be updated.